# returning an assignment expression

Tags: c#, string, return, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

While I was working on some of older code in C#, I encountered a code which irked me.

Without much ado, it goes something like this:

```
private string foo(string _text)
{
   /* some manipulation on _text */
   return _text = Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
}
```

It's the last line which irks me; I'm from C background, and I can understand that the code is in effect trying to return a decoded _text variable. Also the value of an assignment operator is the left operand, so I can see it.

Yet I still find it irksome.

Is it a ordinate practice in C# that I need to get accustomed to?

To me the last line should simply be

```
return Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
```

and not be an assignment expression. Is there a deeper C# feature which I'm not aware of?

Comment: `_text` definitely isn't a global variable, it's the method's parameter.

Comment: Is the assignment actually necessary? You won't be able to do anything with `_text` afterwards and it is most likely going out of scope.

Comment: @lc. that's what I was partially asking; if it had any meaning. Based on what I've gathered, I suppose not.

Comment: @JaceKim Don't think so. It might have been refactored from a time when `_text` was a field, in which case `foo` would both set the value of `_text` and return the value?

Comment: @lc. unfortunately it's a fresh commit. Anyways the question has been answered and I'm satisfied. thanks guys.

Comment: @JaceKim: Were you able to receive any sort of explanation from the person who made commit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> While I was working on some of older code in C#, I encountered a code which irked me.

There are numerous irksome problems here. Let's list them all.

```
private string foo(string _text)
{
   /* some manipulation on _text */
   return _text = Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
}
```

> It's the last line which irks me

The comment is also irksome. Local variables are *cheap*. There is no need to erase the original value of `_text`. Instead, make a new local variable and manipulate that. That way, when you are debugging *at any point in the method you can know what the original argument was*. (Remember, the original argument might be eligible for garbage collection the moment the variable is overwritten, and therefore could be lost forever.)

Do not write over a formal parameter without a very good reason. It makes it harder to debug.

> the value of an assignment operator is the left operand, so I can see it.

That is correct in this case but subtly wrong in general; the value of an assignment operator in C# is the value of the *right* operand *after being converted to the type associated with the left hand side*.  Remember, the left hand side might not have a value; it could be a write-only property.

> Is it a ordinate practice in C# that I need to get accustomed to?

There is a standard practice here, yes.  What is bizarre about this usage is (1) that the variable chosen is a formal, and (2) that the assignment is combined with the `return`.

It would be a standard practice in C# to say:

```
string decoded = Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
return decoded;
```

Now you might wonder what the compelling benefit of this is over what you suggest:

```
return Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
```

The answer is: before Visual Studio 2013, there was no facility in the debugger to examine the returned value of a method call! Therefore if you wanted to see what the value returned by `HtmlDecode` was while debugging you had the following choices:

- Debug at the assembly level and look at the contents of EAX
- Step into `HtmlDecode` and examine its state
- Step out of the current method and examine whatever the return value was assigned to
- **Assign the result to an otherwise useless local variable** and then examine the local in the debugger

Since the first three are horrid and the last one is easy, that's what many C# programmers got in the habit of doing.

If you do this and then do *not* use the resulting local, the C# compiler knows that this is a common practice and deliberately suppresses the "you wrote to a local you then never read from" warning.  It only gives that warning if the local had a constant written to it, in which case you already knew what it was at compile time and don't typically need to examine it in the debugger.

Hopefully now that VS2013 finally supports this frequently-requested feature, this sort of pattern will gradually disappear.

Comment: if you could, would you mind expanding on this remark? "Remember, the original argument might be eligible for garbage collection the moment the variable is overwritten, and therefore could be lost forever"

Comment: @Jace Kim: If the variable is overwritten it might be the case that the argument has no live references left and the GC can collect it.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is redundant and **not** a C# practice.

Doing so while ReSharper is active will also give the warning

> Value assigned is not used in any execution path

As you mentioned, this code would indeed be the best practice

```
return Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
```

Also, since the decode is part of the manipulations on _text, it would also be valid to separate the assignation and return statement, to keep the logic in the same block :

```
/* Other manipulations on _text */
_text = Server.HtmlDecode(_text);

return _text;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a silly thing to do, and it sacrifices readability in the name of cramming more code onto one line. That's almost always a bad thing.

In this case, it actually serves no purpose whatsoever. `_text` is the method's parameter, and changing it in the method body accomplishes nothing. The string that was passed to the method will not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same result. It's most common to see the latter, or:

```
_text = Server.HtmlDecode(_text);
return _text;
```

(I like either the above or `return Server.HtmlDecode(_text);`, but not the way it is in the code you're reading)

Comment: I prefer `Server.HtmlDecode(_text);`. That being said, I prefer using a locally declared string to store string manipulations.

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to know if there were some obscure C# feature that I wasn't aware of, or that I couldn't find. Coming from C and Lisp, C# seems to be a lot of black magickary going on behind.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no deeper C# feature in this case, doing the assignment in the `return` statement is simply pointless. It only makes it harder to follow what the code is supposed to be doing.

The only difference from what you propose is that the decoded value is assigned to the `_text` variable, but as that variable isn't used any more, it doesn't matter what it's value is when the method ends. The parameter is a local variable inside the method that does't affect anything outside the method.

Comment: a follow-up question would be if return statement returns the value of _text, or 'the result of the assignment expression'. It's a very pedantic issue. Do the C# programmers use 'value-of-assignment-expression'? I've avoided it for readability in C but I've seen enough code that employ it to be weary of it.

Comment: @JaceKim: The `return` statement returns the value of the expression, and the value of the assignment expression is the value that was assigned. The value is not read from the variable again to be returned. C# programmers sometimes uses assignments as expressions, but not very frequently. It's mostly used when the alternative would be a more complex control structure, for example when a value determines if a loop should continue; `while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null) ...`